# Understanding the effects of source faults on load voltages in three phase systems

Tags: three-phase

I have heard that an open circuit in a wye connected source affects the voltage across the loads (whether they be delta or wye), as shown in the following diagrams.
[image]

[image]

I have also heard that an open circuit fault in a delta connected source will not affect the load voltages, as shown in the following diagram.

[image]

Finally, I have heard that if the wye source has a neutral wire, it will not affect the load voltages, in contrast to the case where it does not have a neutral wire.

I would like to understand the reasons for all of these things, and in particular how it can be proven mathematically.

Comment: Since the diagrams contain ``winding failed open!`` is the question about the effect of _open circuit faults_ rather than _short circuit faults_?

Comment: Yes. Sorry. Although I'm curious about whether short circuit faults would have a similar effect.